# Oracle VBox (Windows 10 Pro, x64) выдаёт чёрный экран при начале установки Debian (netinst, amd64)

Tags: windows, virtualbox, vmware, виртуальная-машина, hyper-v

Ранее уже гуглил подобную проблему. Суть проблемы довольно простая, поставил **Oracle VBox**, обновил, с обновлением поставились и расширения к нему, процессор вроде как умеет в виртуализацию. В компонентах Windows у меня отключён Hyper-V. Как и большинство других компонентов какие могут мешать поднятию виртуалки. У меня Windows x64 Pro, она **не лицензионная**, крякнутая, но вроде как это не должно мешать. Для наглядности ниже прилагаю скриншот (cм. внизу)


Так-же, у меня очень старенький компьютер, на нём **всего** 4 Гб ОЗУ. Но, ведь Debian/Ubuntu без графического окружения, требуют от 512 Мб, я выделял им как 1 Гб, так и 1.5 Гб ОЗУ, чёрный экран имеет вид простого чёрного экрана, а между нажатием установки, и появлением чёрного экрана проскальзывает небольшой экран с консолью, но сразу же падает, ничего там успеть сделать не выйдет, после чего нет ни приглашения консоли, никаких действий, ожидал около 20 минут, в свёрнутом состоянии *(VBox писал что виртуалка работает)*. 3D в VBox, отключен! Ниже прилагаю скриншот, с панели управления "О Системе" (cм. внизу)


Подскажите в чём может быть главная проблема?

[image: Cписок компонентов Винды]
[image: Скриншот с вкладки "О Системе"]
[image: Настройки VBox]
[image: Виртуалка грузится, такая она до момента нажатия установки]
[image: Что происходит после начала установки]

Comment: Не хватает оперативной памяти у компьютера для работы Hyper-V. Можно попробовать обычную виртуализацию процессора использовать. Возможно её нужно включить в биосе компьютера.

Comment: Также в настройках виртуального окружения в VirtualBox → «Система» → «Ускорение» можно выбрать тип виртуализаии и установить галочки для использования виртуализации процессора.

Comment: @neon1ks, аппаратная виртуализация была включена. Проблема оказалась не с виртуализацией а количеством выделенной VRAM, стандартно там выделяется 16 МБ, что явно мало. При указывании более 64 МБ, все прекрасно работает. Причем с аппаратной виртуализации работает быстрее, ваш совет оказался очень полезным!

Comment: Чтож, будем знать)

Comment: hyper-v это же гипервизор, он над виндой работает, пока его не уберёте никакие vm работать не будут. Не знаю деталей hyper-v но подозревааю, что после снятия галочки в компонентах базовая часть остаётся

Comment: @PavelGridin, я отключал пошем. Он в состоянии offline, никакого Hyper-V нет и не было, все убралось под чистую (по крайней мере так говорит пош). В любом случае спасибо за инфу.

Comment: ну а просто Install попробовать, без графики... вот графика у vbox самая паршивая и непредсказуемая часть

Comment: @PavelGridin, да проблема уже решена. Я ставил через install, псевдо-графика. Там хрень была с количеством VRAM-а который я выделил на виртуалку, нужно от 64 Мб выделять для VBox-a. И ставить виртуализацию через процессор, а то для хайпер-ви не хватает ресурсов (4 ггб, маловато) это сказали и в чатике для сисадминов тоже. Что мол слишком мало ресурсов для хайпер-ви.

Суть в том что установщику нужно что-то вроде 32-64 МБ видеопамяти, но VBox ставит 16, а потом получаешь чёрный экран, и не знаешь что делать. Прикольные настройки вообщем :)

Answer (score 2):

Проблема оказалась исключительно в настройках VRAM самого VBox-a, стандартно она выставляется как 16 МБ, чего для виртуализации процесса установки операционной системы крайне мало. При выставлении аппаратной виртуализации (галочка на **Nest Padding**) система адекватно начинает установку, как показала практика можно и через паравиртуализацию.